# For what purpose 'no-use-before-define' warns about declared functions?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am confused about an *eslint* warning from rule [`no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define):

This rule makes perfect sense to avoid errors caused by function expressions, such as

```js
// Case 1:
// Incorrect code; eslint warns me for good reason:

runMe() // Error: Cannot access 'runMe' before initialization

const runMe = () => { alert('expression, not hoisted') }
```

However, when declaring functions, it is perfectly okay to call a function before it is defined (thanks to the JS hoisting mechanism)

```js
// Case 2:
// Correct code; for what reason does eslint warns me about this?

runMe() // Works!

function runMe() { alert('definition, hoisted') }
```

Is there a reason, why *eslint* treats both cases the same way (i.e. does it make the script run faster/disable hoisting/has some other impact)?

And the second question: Can I configure *eslint* to only warn me about the first case but treat the declarative function style as valid?

Comment: Because it's used in the source before it's defined in the source. This may make reasoning about the code harder, hence the error. Don't know if you can configure it too take hoisting into account.

Comment: 2nd Q: no - it's all or nothing. 1st Q: obviously you know the answer or you would not have asked Q2. It is the rules someone else has set for you to follow.

Comment: So the reason is just "making the code easy to read" (or "personal taste"). There's no performance gain, or that following the rule somehow disables hoisting etc?

Comment: Most eslint rules are either personal taste or avoiding common errors, rarely about performance.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I believe the "first question" you refer to is asking more along the lines of *"In which way, if any, does hoisting affect code execution, such that ESLint deems a warning necessary?"* Thus I don't think it's fair to say that OP already knows the answer. I suppose it's up to interpretation though.

Comment: @TylerRoper - good point. I didn't read it that way. Thanks.

Comment: Consider `runMe(); const value = 'used in declaration'; function runMe() { console.log(value); }`. Should it warn or not? In general, it is safer not to rely on hoisting. Its purpose is to allow defining mutually recursive functions, not to allow calls before definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [rule documentation page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) (emphasis mine):

> In JavaScript, prior to ES6, variable and function declarations are
>   hoisted to the top of a scope, so it’s possible to use identifiers
>   before their formal declarations in code. **This can be confusing and
>   some believe it is best to always declare variables and functions
>   before using them.**

There does not appear to be a way to warn only if not hoisted. You could create a [custom plugin](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this eslint-warning for function declarations, which is safe, since they are hoisted anyway at runtime - e.g. like this:

```
"rules": {    
  "no-use-before-define": ["error", {"functions": false}]
}
```

From the docs:

> functions (boolean) - The flag which shows whether or not this rule
> checks function declarations. If this is true, this rule warns every
> reference to a function before the function declaration. Otherwise,
> ignores those references. Function declarations are hoisted, so it’s
> safe. Default is true.

Head over to the docs for more details: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-use-before-define

Comment: This does not work with arrow functions